# ember.js: perform action every time controller is visited

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app, I'm using a global variable to keep track of an important piece of state (whether or not the user has opened a project). It's used as a condition when drawing other views (like a navigation menu).

Right now I have controllers setting the global variable like so:

```
App.ProjectsOverviewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ["application"]
  init: ->
    @set("controllers.application.isProjectSet", true)
```

But this only happens the first time a user visits that controller. How can I have this happen every time, not just upon the initial `init`?

Or, if anyone can suggest a better way to do this within the tools Ember provides, I'd certainly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimentation, I think this will work when performed on [Route#activate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate):

```
App.ProjectsOverviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find("project", params.project_id)
  activate: ->
    @controllerFor("application").set("isProjectSet", true)
```